# Codeforces 765C. getting wrong answer dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

Problem Link: https://codeforces.com/contest/1625/problem/C

Code Link: https://codeforces.com/contest/1625/submission/142498235

Question:

There is a road of length *l*(given) having *n* boards at its coordinates, having a number written on it, which specify the time taken to travel unit distance till we cross other board which tells new time to travel unit distance and so on.

Given - First board is always present at coordinate 0.
We need to remove at most k boards and minimise our time taken to travel.

Condition: We cannot remove the first board(which is at coordinate 0).
We are given 3 variables:

n,l,k(1≤n≤500, 1≤ℓ≤10^5,  0≤k≤n−1)

n = no. of boards in the road

l = length of the road

k = maximum boards that we can remove

Next line contains *n* integers i.e. the coordinates of the boards.

Next line contains *n* integers i.e. the time mentioned on the boards.

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define int long long

int findDistance(vector<pair<int, int>> v, int n, int i, int k, int tm, int l, vector<vector<int>> &dp) {
    if (i == n) {
        return tm;       // returns time taken to reach last coordinate
    }
    if (dp[i][k] != -1) { // if answer already present return it
        return dp[i][k];
    }
    int a = INT_MAX, b = INT_MAX;
    int c;                   // coordinate of next board
    if (i != n - 1) {
        c = v[i + 1].first;
    }
    else c = l;   // coordinate of our destination
    if (k != 0 && i != 0) {        // when we can remove a board (We can't remove 1st pole i.e. when i != 0 and k != 0. Here k is the maximum board we can remove)
//removing a board
        a = findDistance(v, n, i + 1, k - 1, tm + ((v[i - 1].second) * (c - v[i].first)), l, dp);
    }
// not removing a board
    b = findDistance(v, n, i + 1, k, tm + ((v[i].second) * (c - v[i].first)), l, dp);

    return dp[i][k] = min(a, b); // return minimum answer
}

void solve()
{
    int n, l, k;            
    cin >> n >> l >> k;    // Takes input Number of roads, Length of the road, maximum signs we can remove.
    vector<pair<int, int>> v(n); // To store coordinate of board and time taken to cross a unit distance till we find a new board
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i].first;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> v[i].second;
    }
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n + 1, vector<int>(k + 1, -1)); // to store our answer
    int ans = findDistance(v, n, 0, k, 0, l, dp); // to find our answer
    cout << ans << "\n";
    return;
}

int32_t main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Input1:

```
4 10 0     --> n, l, k (no. of boards, length o the road or the final coordinate to reach, maximum 
               boards that we can remove.)
0 3 4 8    --> coordinates of the board 
5 8 3 6    --> time taken to cross unit distance after crossing that board 
               if we do not remove that board.
```

In this example, we cannot remove the signs. So the answer is 47(Total time is 3⋅5+1⋅8+4⋅3+2⋅6=47).

Input2:

```
4 10 2
0 3 4 8
5 8 3 6
```

In this example, we may remove the second and the fourth sign. In this case, we need to drive four kilometers in 4⋅5=20 minutes, and then six kilometers in 6⋅3=18, so the total time is 4⋅5+6⋅3=38 minutes.

I have solved this question using top down dynamic programming but it is giving WA on testcase 5. But I am not getting what I've done wrong.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. What is the code supposed to do? What is the input? What is the output?

Comment: I've edited the question. Please check

Comment: Perhaps helpful [My solution kept on failing on Pretest #5. Can anyone explain me the correct solution pls](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/codeforces-problem-c/15919)